# update boolean postgresql at midnight everyday?

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have a boolean column named "taken" how would I set it so that for every column the entry is set to false at midnight everyday? And how would file be run? is it just a stand alone php file that works every night?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way of dealing with that is to **avoid it**. Don't run a daily batch doing a general update, it's costly, and not necessary.

Instead, replace the boolean column with a date. Set it to the current date instead of setting the boolean to true, and to null instead of setting the boolean to false.

Then read the value like this, assuming the column is `date_taken`:

```
SELECT coalesce((date_taken=current_date),false) AS taken, ... FROM tablename;
```

- if `date_taken=current_date`, it means it has been set today, so it yields true.
- if `date_taken<>current_date`, it has been set but earlier, so it yields false, as if the midnight update batch has been run.
- if `date_taken` is null, it has never been set or set to null, and the `coalesce()` yields false.